# Rails app not displaying ajax requested data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, templates, pagination

I am making an AJAX call in my app. The call is supposed to get the second page of paginated content and display it below the first page. The call is being made successfully, only the data the AJAX is fetching comes back as JS as detailed in the code below:

```
Started GET "/links?_=1451434087187&page=4" for ::1 at 2015-12-29 19:08:13 -0500
Processing by LinksController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1451434087187", "page"=>"4"}
```

If not using an AJAX call and I just click on one of the paginated links in my application, the data requested comes back as html:

```
Started GET "/links?_=1451434246208&page=1" for ::1 at 2015-12-29 19:11:13 -0500
Processing by LinksController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1451434246208", "page"=>"1"}
  Link Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  ORDER BY "links"."cached_votes_score" DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links"
```

I included a respond_to in my controller to try and accept the JS data, but it did not work:

```
  def index
    @links = Link.order(cached_votes_score: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
```

link.coffee.js:

```
jQuery ->
    $(window).scroll ->
        url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
        if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
            $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
            $.getScript(url)
```

index.js.erb:

```
    $('#link').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
    <% if @links.next_page %>
     $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@links) %>');
    <% else %>
        $('.pagination').remove();
    <% end %>

_link.html.erb:
<!-- order links based on total number of votes -->

  <div class="link row clearfix">
    <h2>

    </h2>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <%= link_to link.url, link %><br>
    </p>

<!-- acts_as_votable for like_link -->
    <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          Upvote
          <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to dislike_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
          Downvote
          <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: Can you show up a copy of your javascript ajax code?

Comment: @VincentAlgayres I edited my question with it

Comment: @Jbur43 Can you kindly show the rendered JavaScript and HTML please? It is a client side issue and it would be easy to debug.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I posted my link partial for my template rendering.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I posted my updated partial, I am still having difficulty getting the contents to display

Comment: I did not have an id of link in my view and I was using that as a selector. This issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a selector of #link in my script, but did not have a div id of link set in my template. Now that I added it, this works great.

`<div class="link row clearfix" id='link'>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <%= link_to link.url, link %><br>
    </p>`